# c# - write string that contains hex values as bytes

Tags: c#, utf-8, filestream

let's say I have a string

```
string hex = "55 6E 6B 6E 6F 77 6E 20 53 70 61 63 65"
```

I want to write these to a file but they should be the bytes itself.
so the result would be Unknown Space.

Is there any way to do that directly instead of first `encoding` it to `utf-8` and write that to the file? the reason I'm asking is that sometimes there is the special character of `utf-8` in the (like e.g. `0xE28780`) which wouldn't work well if I first split the string into chars of each value.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with `string.Split`, `Convert.ToByte`, and `FileStream` or `File.WriteAllBytes`

```
string hex = "55 6E 6B 6E 6F 77 6E 20 53 70 61 63 65";
var bytes = hex.Split(' ')
               .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16))
               .ToArray();

using (var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\test2.dat",FileMode.Create))
   fs.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);

// or even easier 

File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\test2.dat",bytes);
```

---

[String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character array.

[Convert.ToByte Method (String, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number in a specified base to
>   an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer.

[FileStream Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Provides a Stream for a file, supporting both synchronous and
>   asynchronous read and write operations.

[File.WriteAllBytes Method (String, Byte[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and
>   then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is
>   overwritten.